# make a tree of items in selectbox in php

Tags: php, tree, drop-down-menu

I have a code to make a tree in my html select box
I've filled the array and generate tree in select box 
 like this :

```
$vertices = array(
    array(
        'id' => 5,
        'name' => 'Child3',
        'parent' => 2,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'name' => 'Child1',
        'parent' => 1,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'name' => 'Child2',
        'parent' => 1,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Cat1',
        'parent' => null,
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Cat2',
        'parent' => null,
    ),
);

/**
 * Generate tree
 */
$subtrees = $trees = array();
foreach ($vertices as $vertex) {
    $v = array(
        'id' => $vertex['id'],
        'name' => $vertex['name'],
        'children' => array(),
    );

    if (isset($subtrees[$vertex['id']])) {
        $v['children'] = $subtrees[$vertex['id']];
    }

    if ($vertex['parent'] === null) {
        $trees[] = $v;
    }
    else if (!isset($subtrees[$vertex['parent']])) {
        $subtrees[$vertex['parent']] = array($v);
    }
    else {
        $subtrees[$vertex['parent']][] = $v;
    }
}
unset($subtrees);

/**
 * Generate HTML
 */

function getSubtreeOptions(array $subtreeRoot, $level = 0)
{
    $html = sprintf('%s<option value="%d">%s%s</option>' . PHP_EOL,
        str_repeat("\t", $level + 1),
        $subtreeRoot['id'],
        $level > 0 ? str_repeat(' ', $level) . '--' : null,
        $subtreeRoot['name']);

    foreach ($subtreeRoot['children'] as $child) {
        $html .= getSubtreeOptions($child, $level + 1);
    }

    return $html;
}

echo '<select name="stuff">' . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($trees as $root) {
    echo getSubtreeOptions($root);
}
echo '</select>';
```

It works fine , but when I want to fill the array by mysql query, It shows nothing in selectbox

this is my db code to fill array :

```
$res = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, parent FROM groups ORDER BY parent DESC, id') or trigger_error('Query failed: ' . mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
$vertices = array();
while ($vertex = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $vertices[] = $vertex;
}
```

where is the problem?

when i print the array.The output is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => test
            [parent] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => test
            [parent] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => test
            [parent] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => test
            [parent] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => test
            [parent] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: check if the array structure of the mysql returned array is same with the given array... `print_r($vertices)`...and check

Comment: Please avoid using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. You can use `mysqli_*` or the PDO.

Comment: I've just updated my post with your print_r($vertices); code

Comment: you have '0' for parent for root node and in $vertices and 'null' in test array and in you code .. you are testing for null .. that might be the reason for problem

Comment: yes you'r right; you can answer and get the best label :). the change is replace 'null' in generate tree with '0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `0` will `null` for `parent` key in `$verties` for those nodes which have no children and you should be fine. 
your `$vertices` array should look like

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [name] => test
        [parent] => 3
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => test
        [parent] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => test
        [parent] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => test
        [parent] => null
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [name] => test
        [parent] => null
    )

 )
```

The reason being in condition

```
 if ($vertex['parent'] === null) {
    $trees[] = $v;
}
```

you are against `null`

Comment: thank you so much.the problem is solved :)

Comment: @AF.P good to help you